# Регистрация распространненого сленга

Tags: жаргон, лексикография, грамотная-речь

Сегодня, особенно в интернет-среде, очень популярно слово "пруф", которое в неформальном общении буквально полностью вытеснило слово "доказательство". При этом большинство людей относят его к сленгу и безаргументно отрицают идеи об офицальной регистрации этого слова. 
Хотелось бы узнать, что вы думаете о подобных идеях, желателен развернутый, аргументированный ответ.

*Так же существует ряд других слов, обладающих подобными "особенностями" (популярность и неприемлемость), но я думаю, обсуждение одного конкретного слова охватит весь спектр мыслей и доводов в отношении подобных идей.*

Answer (score 2):

Моё мнение: юзать и беспруфно расшаривать фейки - неселфреспектная имплементация фени.

Answer (score 2):

Сегодня действительно  очень много неоправданных слов. Такие слова, как пруф, юзать относятся к сленгу и  вряд ли приживутся. У всех этих слов есть полные русские аналоги. Обычно то или иное слово получает паспорт, когда ассимилируется и попадает в народ; некоторым просто лень переводить эти слова, вот и получаются такие заимствования.

Answer (score 0):

Тургенева на них нет! Зачем придумывать искусственный язык? Пусть лучше учат, что есть.

Comment: Инна, сколько бы ни придумывали  - эти слова вряд ли приживутся.

Comment: Полностью согласна!